# SSIS Loading Excel File with Dynamic Columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I feel like this shouldn't be a difficult issue, but I am newer to SSIS and am having trouble finding a solution. I am trying to load two columns of data, but each month I get a new file with an additional column, and a new header. For example, starting in January I receive a file with two columns:

| Location | Jan-21 |
| --- | --- |
| Texas | 100 |
| Maine | 500 |

Then in February I receive a file like the below:

| Location | Jan-21 | Feb-21 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Texas | 100 | 250 |
| Maine | 500 | 450 |

Each month a new column is added with new data, but I only need to load the newest column's data. I can't figure out how to do this in SSIS, is it possible?. I'm loading from an Excel source to a staging table in a database with two columns (Location & Total).

Comment: Your problem is with this phrase: "each month I get a new file with an additional column [...]". The input data should be structured to add rows over time, not new columns. Perhaps you could only these columns: Location, Date, and <DataValue>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS requires a fixed format - that is just your 2 columns or all columns.  If the spreadsheet is constantly changing like this - you are not going to be able to import from that spreadsheet.

There are probably ways to setup a separate sheet in Excel that references the specific column you need, but I wouldn't know how to do that.

If looking at just SSIS and I had no other options, I would do the following:

1. Script Task - get the file to be processed and identify the month to be processed.
2. Use a condition to redirect to one of 12 different data flows, depending on which file is being processed.
3. 12 separate file connection - one for each month
4. Each data flow then selects just the columns needed

Another option would be a pre-processor where you process the file using something like powershell and create a CSV file of just the contents you need.